# No se me guardan las palabras ni utilizando el localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

vengo estancado en mi código desde hace unos días. Mi intención es agregar palabras mediante un input y que queden registradas en un array de otro sitio web. Intenté llevando la función que agrega palabras al archivo js original e invocándola en el input html de la otra página; también probé con el localStorage.setItem y localStorage.getItem para luego aplicar un .push y tampoco pude. Soy bastante nuevo en el mundo de la programación; si alguien me podría dar una mano estaría agradecido. Comparto mi código:

```js
// JS principal (challenge02.js)
let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];

let palabra = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random()*palabras.length)];

let palabraConGuiones = palabra.replace(/./g, "_ ");

let palabrasaux= localStorage.setItem('keyPalabras', palabras);

let contadorFallos = 6;

document.querySelector('#salida00').innerHTML = palabraConGuiones; //Acá me sale error

document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){

    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()

});
```

```js
// Segundo js (agregar-palabra.js)
document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

});

let datos = [];

let palabrasguardadas= localStorage.getItem('keyPalabras',palabras);

function agregarPalabra(){

    let dato = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();
// cuando hago el push me sale error
    palabrasguardadas.push(dato);

}

function mostrarPalabra(){

    let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    resultado.innerHTML = '';

    for(let dato of datos){

        let datoParrafo = document.createElement('p');

        datoParrafo.innerText = dato;

        resultado.appendChild(datoParrafo);

    }

}
```

```html
//Html del segundo js (agregar-palabra.js)
//invoco la función
<input type='text' id="texto">
    
<input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Guardar Palabra' onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>

<input type='button' id="mostrar-palabra" value = 'Mostrar palabras' onclick= 'mostrarPalabra()'>
```

Agradezco la información que recibí sobre el uso del localStorage, pero le doy vueltas y no se que es lo que debería modificar.

Comment: El localStorage solo funciona dentro del mismo sitio web, y tu dices **que queden registradas en un array de otro sitio web**... ahi tienes el problema... si quieres eso ya solo te queda usar bases de datos comunes o escribir archivos en disco que puedas recuperar desde ambos

Comment: Ah ya entendí ahora. Te agradezco la información y la paciencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `localStorage` solo funciona con distintas páginas dentro de un mismo dominio web.

Desde un dominio podrás acceder a los items del `localStorage` de ese mismo dominio pero no de ningún otro dominio ya que esto sería peligroso y una brecha de seguridad.

Por ejemplo desde `example.com` puedo acceder los items de ese dominio

```
window.localStorage.setItem('test','TEST');
window.localStorage.getItem('test') // <-- TEST
```

Pero si accedo a otro dominio por ejemplo `example2.com` no podré acceder al item anterior pero si podré crear otros para este dominio.

```
window.localStorage.getItem('test') // <-- null
```